# Check if a specific window is displayed on the screen using objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am using Objective C to automate the working of an application. I need to check if on find replace, the alert `start from beginning` is displayed or not. How can I do this using Objective C?

Comment: I believe that it totally depends on the views / controls that you are using in this application. Please provide details for those too. Currently the question is too vague

Comment: find/replace is of the type AXFloatingWindow and the 'start from beginning' is of the type AXWindow. NSGenericWindow class is used for the development of both

Answer (score 0):

I used the NSAccessibility class to find the desired window by passing the values for the attributes AXIdentifier and AXRole. It works fin.